# Slow connection at the first connect on MVC Application + Thinktecture IdentityServer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, iis, yslow, thinktecture-ident-server

We are using MVC Application and Thinktecture Identity Server.

When first user connects to the application it takes >30+ seconds and subsequent connections are very quick (<3s) for home page and also for login page (Thinktecture page)

We are tried giving 'Idle Time Out(minutes)' for the application pool to 0 (worker process will never shut down)

Apart from this any other setting we over looked or any other suggestions on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: IIS7.5 Has a useful feature that allows you to control what happens when an app pool expires. You can have the app restart.

Comment: The [Application Initialization Module for IIS](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization) will "warm up" your application which should decrease the response time for the first request. I believe @lrb is hinting about using this module.

Comment: After giving  'Idle Time Out(minutes)' for the application pool to 0 also will the IIS take time?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure in MVC but in asp.net we have same scenario with lag hit for first user. Once all dll are created after first request.. they are shared with others so next response will be faster. To avoid this you can publish your solution as Precompiled dll

Comment: Yes we do publish the site and deploy in the production environment. Even then we are facing the same issue ):